# How to convert a simple SQL request into Apache PIG script?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, join, apache-pig

I would like to convert the following SQL request into a PIG script.
My problem is that I am currently using to many `JOIN` into the script, that seems to make the PIG run slowly.

How can I optimize the code ?

SQL Request :

```
Select distinct
A.somethingA1, A.somethingA2, A.somethingA3,
B.somethingB1, B.somethingB2, B.somethingB3,
C.somethingC1, C.somethingC2,
D.getFieldX as fieldX,
F.somethingF1

From

TABLE_A A,
TABLE_B B,
TABLE_C C,
TABLE_D D,
TABLE_E E,
TABLE_F F

Where

A.getField1 = B.getField1
And A.getField2 = E.getField2
And A.getField3 = C.getField3
And A.getField3 = D.getField4
And A.getField5 = F.getField6
And F.getField7 = D.getField7
And D.getFieldX = 'X'
```

Do I need to use several `JOIN` one by one even if that may create a huge final object with so many field ? Or can I just use a simple `FILTER` for it ?

Actually, I am not sure I can use `FILTER` on datas from different tables. Can I ?

So far, I've been using at least 5 `JOIN` in the script and that looks not optimized at all !
Here's what I did :

```
A = load 'TABLE_A' using avrostorage();
B = load 'TABLE_B' using avrostorage();
C = load 'TABLE_C' using avrostorage();
D = load 'TABLE_D' using avrostorage();
E = load 'TABLE_E' using avrostorage();
F = load 'TABLE_F' using avrostorage();

data1 = JOIN A by getField1, B by getField1;
data1 = FOREACH data GENERATE A::somethingA1, A::somethingA2, A::somethingA3, A::getField2, A::getField3, B::somethingB1, B::somethingB2, B::somethingB3;

data2 = JOIN data1 by getField2, E by getField2;
data2 = FOREACH data2 GENERATE data1::A::somethingA1, data1::A::somethingA2, data1::A::somethingA3, data1::A::getField2, data1::A::getField3, data1::B::somethingB1, data1::B::somethingB2, data1::B::somethingB3;

dump data2;
describe data2;
```

Etc etc.. until reaching the final tables.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax! Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: @jarlh I am sorry I don't get the question.. MySQL or Oracle ? I use both actually .. What do you mean by explicit `JOIN` ? That's why I am currently using actually.

Comment: @hacks4life, you need to optimize this sql script or a pig script ? it you want to get a pig script, can you please post your what you tried so far ?

Comment: @54l3d sure I can. I need to adapt this SQL script into a PIG script.

Answer (score 0):

Your script will be translated into many MapReduce jobs, as number of joins or more, and this is the bottle neck of Hadoop !

Its good to prune column asap, but reducing the number of MR jobs is more important. Try to do it in one step using a multiple join it may have less MR jobs :

```
data1 = JOIN A by getField1, B by getField1, C by getField1 -- ...;
data2 = FOREACH data1 GENERATE A::somethingA1, A::somethingA2, --..;
```

And if you have a small relation, consider to use [replicated](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref1.html#Replicated+Joins) keyword.